# Getting java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit2, gson

I know there are similar questions on the same error that I'm getting but none of them actually worked for me. The problem is when I try to use `GsonConverterFactory` with my **Retrofit client**, it gives me this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':client:transformClassesWithJarMergingForOCStagingDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class
```

There is indeed a solution which actually suggests me to remove the `gson` module from the `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0` library in following way-

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson.annotations', module: 'annotations'
    }
```

But if I do this, then the `GsonCoverter` stops working and **all network requests are failing**.

I'm adding the details of all my dependencies in below.

```
dependencies {

   // Using sfl4j allows us to replace different loggers later, if desired
   compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
   compile project(':adyen')
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
   compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.1.1'
   compile('com.miairline:domain:5.1.19') {
      exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
      exclude group: 'log4j'
      exclude group: 'commons-logging'
      exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
   }
   compile 'android.tools.support:annotations:20.0.1'
   compile 'com.alexgilleran:icesoap:1.0.2'
   compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0'
   compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
   compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.7'
   compile 'com.samskivert:jmustache:1.10'
   compile 'org.alljoyn.bus:alljoyn-android:15.04.00a'
   compile 'com.radaee.pdfex:com-radaee-pdfex:2.6.2'
   compile 'com.adyen.services:android-lib:1.10p7'
   compile 'net.christophersnow:sync-android-p2p:0.0.6-RC3' 

   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
      transitive = true
   }
   compile 'com.iecisa:mposplugin_production:1.25@aar'
   compile('org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:2.1-M7') {
      exclude group: 'org.osgi', module: 'org.osgi.core'
   }
   compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.simple:2.1-M7'
   testCompile('junit:junit:4.10',
        'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21', 
        'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3',
        'com.miairline.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:18',
        'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.0',
        'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.5.1',
        'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.5.1',
        'org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:1.5.1',
        'com.github.rtyley:android-screenshot-celebrity:1.9')
   compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
   compile 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v0.9.6'
   compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
      exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
   }
   compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0') {
      exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson.annotations', module: 'annotations'
   }
   compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.2') {
      // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
      exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
   }
   compile('com.github.bright:slf4android:0.1.3') {
      transitive = true
   }
}
```

I've also tried looking into the dependency tree and found nothing duplicate over there. The strange thing is, it's working for other project and not in this. Also attaching the `defautlConfig` for my `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: Why are u using both gsonConverter and jacksonConverter for retrofit? Wouldn't it be better to simply use one.

Comment: Oops sorry, that's an editing mistake. I'll rectify it. :)